# How to get client printer details in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, wmi

I am working on web based application (Asp.net Mvc3 Razor,Sql server 2012) in which i want to `get printers that connected in client system`

To get printer names in windows installed system i have used WMI(windows media instrumentation), but how i will  get `linux` based system information for the same purpose.

Comment: Why does a web based application care about the printers installed on the client machine? Sounds like you might be using the wrong tool for whatever this job is.

Comment: (Ever actually used WMI *in* ASP.NET to get client printer details? That'd be some magic, although not entirely unfeasible on a *corporate network*.)

Comment: the system developed for intranet user application and they want to connect local printer for printing .For each action they put different printer in different client system.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Web-browsers do not expose details of attached printers in HTTP headers, nor is there any exposed browser scripting API for printing.

The only workaround is to use a Java applet or ActiveX control that breaks out of the browser sandbox and queries printers. However be warned that neither approach will work on the modern Internet - ActiveX was effectively made dead around 2002 and Java is fast on the way out too.

Flash does have a rudimentary printing API which may return the names of attached printers, but it isn't reliable.

In response to part-2: obviously WMI doesn't work on Linux, you might get somewhere with CUPS or querying under `/dev`, but Linux doesn't have anything like WMI.

Why do you want the details of attached printers anyway? A web server application cannot command the client to print anything. And WMI will only tell you about the server the application is running on.

Answer (score 1):

I think via the `CUPS` web interface you can achieve the task. 
[Check this](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/05/17/configure-linux-printing-via-web-browser/)